# Snapping Header: Which controls to use inside ObjectPageHeaderContent

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am verifying the guidelines for [Snapping Header](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/ui-components/snapping-header).

I would like to know which controls are used as children of ObjectPageHeaderContent to prepare forms with label-text pairs. Actually I'm using a VerticalLayout with ObjectStatus controls and another VerticalLayout with a Title and NumericContent to prepare the item like 3rd item in the ObjectPageHeaderContent.
However the result does not look like the example. The guidelines explain FormFacet and KeyValueFacet, but did not understand that. How can I achieve the same result as in the given example.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [ObjectPageHeaderContent](https://plnkr.co/edit/92s96ysFXwDcs10AmFvo?p=preview)

In this example I used the original coding from [sap.uxap.sample.HeaderContent](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.uxap.sample.HeaderContent/preview)

I also used Vertical Layout and added Title, to make it look like the mentioned design element “plain text facet”.
It also renders in multiple lines.
In this case, “plain text facet” is just a term used by design, to describe this element.
The implementation of this design element is accomplished using different UI5 controls.

```
            <ObjectPageHeaderContent>
                           <content>
                                           <layout:VerticalLayout>
                                                           <m:ObjectStatus title="User ID" text="12345678"/>
                                                           <m:ObjectStatus title="Functional Area" text="Developement"/>
                                                           <m:ObjectStatus title="Cost Center" text="PI DFA GD Programs and Product"/>
                                                           <m:ObjectStatus title="Email" text="email@address.com"/>
                                           </layout:VerticalLayout>


                                           <layout:VerticalLayout>
                                           <m:Title text="YourHeader" titleStyle="H4"/>
                                           <m:Text width="200px"
                                                                          text="Hi, I'm Denise. I am passionate about what I do and I'll go the extra mile to make the customer win."/>
                                                           <m:ObjectStatus title="Email" text="email@address.com"/>
                                           </layout:VerticalLayout>


                                           <m:ObjectStatus text="In Stock" state="Error"/>
```

Please describe the other small changes, so that we can look at them.